# how to get an incremental power matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I wanted to compute the following matrix in Matlab:

```
    g=[I
       A 
       .
       .
       .
      A^N]
```

I used the following program in Matlab:

```
A=[2 3;4 1];
s=A;
for n=1:1:50
   s(n)=A.^n;
end
g=[eye(1,1),s];
```

I am getting the following error:

> In an assignment  `A(I) = B`, the number of elements in `B` and `I` must be the same.
>       Error in `s_x_calcu_v1` (line 5)
>       `s(n)=A.^n;`

Comment: you are mixing two operations in your question: `A^N` is **not** `A.^n` - do you want to compute matrix product or element-wise products?

Comment: I wanted to do here A to the power N where n starts from 1 to 50,with 1 increment each time.

Comment: So you want matrix power and **not** element-wise powers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to assign a matrix to a single element. In matlab calling `s(n)` mean you get the nth element of `s`, regardless of the dimensions of s. You can use a three dimensional matrix

```
N = 50;
A=[2 3;4 1];

[nx,ny] = size(A);
s(nx,ny,N) = 0; %makes s a nx x ny x N matrix
for n=1:1:N
    s(:,:,n)=A.^n; %Colon to select all elements of that dimension
end
g=cat(3, eye(size(A)) ,s); %Add the I matrix of same size as A
```

Or a vectorized version

```
s = bsxfun(@power, A(:), 1:N);
s = reshape(s,2,2,N);
g = cat(3, eye(size(A)) ,s);
```

And a third solution using `cumprod`

```
s = repmat(A(:), [1 N]);
s = cumprod(s,2);
s = reshape(s,2,2,N);
g = cat(3, eye(size(A)) ,s);
```

Comment: `cumprod` saves computations!

Answer (score 3):

Your `s` array is a 2-by-2 array, you cannot index it to store the result of your compuation at each step of your loop.

For this, the simpler is probably to define `s` as a cell:

```
% --- Definitions
A = [2 3;4 1];
N = 50;

% --- Preparation
s = cell(N,1);

% --- Computation
for n=1:N
    s{n} = A.^n;
end
```

Best,

Comment: I wanted to do here A to the power N where n starts from 1 to 50,with 1 increment each time.

Answer (score 2):

When you loop from `1` to `N` computing each time `A.^n` you are doing **LOTS** of redundant computations! Note that

```
A.^n = (A.^(n-1)).*A; %//element-wise power
A^n = (A^n) * A; %// matrix power
```

Therefore,

```
A = [2 3;4 1];
N = 50;
s = cell(N+1,1);
s{1} = eye(size(A,1));
for ii=1:N
    s{ii+1} = s{ii}.*A; %// no powers, just product!
end
g = vertcat( s{:} );
```

BTW, the same holds if you want to compute **matrix** power (instead of element-wise powers), all you need is changing to `s{ii+1} = s{ii}*A;`